# adjective describing middle distance (neither near nor far)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective that is somewhere between near and far?

Comment: I rather doubt there would be a single-word adjective. Why would you want it? There's normally no reason to mention distance at all unless it's *actually* either "near" or "far", or you need to reassure someone by saying something is "**not too far**", for example.

Comment: What about "halfway"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yeah, the "not foo far" idea is kind of what I'm getting at. It's strange that we have only "far" and "near", but in the sense of temperature we have "hot", "warm", "lukewarm", "cool", and "cold".

Comment: The terms _middle distant_ and _mid(-)distant_ can be found on Google, the latter being commoner than the former (which is rare). If one argues for compound status (the former is probably not common enough), one can call them 'words'.

Comment: @ Jason: I think you have to make up your mind whether the reassurance you seek to provide is *not too **far*** or *not too **near[by]***. The latter might apply if you were selling your townhouse and wanted to assure a potential buyer that it was *not **too** near* the town centre shops, nightlife, etc. If you search Google Books for "not too near" you'll see it's often conjoined with "not too far", *because there isn't a single commonly-used word to cover the concept*. Except metaphorically, as in *Earth is in the Sun's [Goldilocks zone](http://science.howstuffworks.com/other-earth1.htm)*

Comment: In a somewhat similar context, trying to distinguish between near, not too far and far to reach destinations, I came across the term "proximal". Reading its definition, I am not sure it is a term that fits the context. Does it?

Answer (score 3):

While not directly related to distance and sometimes having a slightly negative quality, you could consider **[middling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/middling)** (which can be an adjective or adverb)

> of middle, medium, or moderate size, degree, or quality

as in

> *They drove a middling distance, not quite halfway through their journey.*

or

> *She traveled only middling far, taking in sights along the way.*

Comment: Hmmm. In my experience, people usually use *middling* as a slightly disparaging way of saying *not really good enough*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hence my warning about *negative quality*. It often can mean *mediocre*. But it can mean *average*, as in *fair to middling*.

Comment: I guess. The problem is that in most contexts where you need to identify a *distance* as neither near nor far, it's likely to be obvious from context that *one* of those is definitely not relevant. So you normally just negate the *other* one, as in *"Don't get too close!"* or *"It's not far to go now!"* I never heard anyone say, for example, *"Keep a middling distance away from that guard dog!"*

Answer (score 2):

I would use "moderate distance" in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Any of "midway", "partway", or "halfway" could work, depending context. Of the three, "partway" is the most general.

Answer (score 0):

*Midrange* would be the word I would use.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a single word, the concept can be expressed by “*not far*”.